# Opera - rotated element outside container loses events

Tags: css, rotation, opera

Check this example on Opera (I have 12.02) http://jsfiddle.net/VArHZ/28/ . Click on red box in blue box (event is triggered) and next click red box outside blue box (event isn't triggered).

Container must have position and z-index.

On other browsers everything is OK. Any solution for Opera?

Comment: Its a bug, reported as DSK-374441.

Comment: In opera 12.10 (1652) everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Do not wrap absolute divs - and you will be able to avoid this bug.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jaAV8/1/